# Issue setting up gmock on visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, googlemock

I'm trying to setup gmock on visual studio 2019.
[I have my folder structure as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc67W.png)

Here i have configured my project with source code(Gmock_project) as a static library. And i have made runtime library as Multi-threaded DLL (/MD). I'm also not using any any precompiled headers.
Then for the unit test project i have done the following properties.

1) Created a new project from the Google Test template (Gmock_Sample).

2) Installed the latest gmock NuGet package from Google (currently v1.10.0).

3) Added the file gtest_main.cc to the project.

4) I have disabled the precompiled headers for gtest_main.cc, gmock-all.cc and gtest-all.cc.

5) I have added the reference of the Gmock_project to the test project.

6) I have included the path of the Gmock_project in VC++directories -> Include directories.

7) I have made runtime library as Multi-threaded DLL (/MD).

8) I have added the path of Gmock_project.lib in Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories.

9) I have included the Gmock_project.lib in Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.

Whenever i'm building Gmock_Sample i.e. test project i'm getting error

```
2>test.obj : error LNK2005: main already defined in gtest_main.obj
2>E:\GMock\Gmock_Sample\Gmock_Sample\x64\Release\Gmock_Sample.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
2>Done building project "Gmock_Sample.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

What could be the issue in configuration?

Comment: I assume you removed the Microsoft googletest package before installing the one from Google? Also, I don't think 8) and 9) are necessary.

Comment: How can i remove the Microsoft googletest package? Because Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-static package based on your answer in another post i didnt see in my visual studio. I only saw Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn package getting created whenever i'm creating the google test template.

Comment: Yes, in your 1) above you are creating a new project from google test template. If you don't remove its static nuget package, you'll get link errors.

Comment: So i should remove Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn package before installing the gmock NuGet package from Google.

Comment: I have tried both your methods to configure the gmock in visual studio. But when i'm linking the code i'm getting the same error mentioned even though i have removed Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn package. So how can i link my source code to my test project.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue today by doing a CMAKE Build for Windows using the googletest repository and then adding the static .lib files and headers into my project.

Here are the steps:

1.Clone googletest Repository ->  [Git-Repository](https://github.com/google/googletest.git)

2.Download CMAKE for Windows. ->  [CMAKE For Windows](https://cmake.org/download/)

3.Install CMAKE, Don't forget to create the System Variables to call it from the CMD.

4.Go to the cloned Repository Folder.

5.Create a folder called "build".

6.Create a folder in your solution application called "googletest-package" -> the    .lib files and headers will be exported here.

7. Run the following command in the cmd or powershell.:

> cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\YourSolutionFolder\googletest-package ..

8. In your build folder you will find now the *googletest-distribution.sln* -> Open the file with a double click.
9. In Visual Studio build the ALL_BUILD Project and then the INSTALL Project this will move the headers and .lib files to the googletest-package folder in your solution.

**--First Stage Finished!**

For the Second Stage we need to do the following since we already have the headers and static libraries its time to link them to the project we want to test.

1. Create a new c++ project in the solution you are trying to test.
   -> Richt Click Solution -> Add -> New Project-> Google Test -> Configuration as Static Library and Link statically.
2. We need to remove first the googletest NU Package installed automatically from the test project to avoid duplicates and clashes with our own googletest build.
   GO TO -> Tools -> NUGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution -> Uninstall Microsoft.googletest.vXXX...
3. Now Add the Include Folders and link the .lib files to the test project as follows:
   -> Right Click in the test project -> C/C++ Tab -> Additional Include Folders

Add the following includes...

"YourSolutionFolder\googletest-package\include"

"YourSolutionFolder\googletest-package\include\gmock"

"YourSolutionFolder\googletest-package\include\gtest"

3. Now Time for the Linker Tab...
   -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories -> Add "YourSolutionFolder\googletest-package\lib"
4. Add the .lib objects as follows:
   Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> Add the following...
   "gmockd.lib;gtestd.lib;mock_maind.lib;gtest_maind.lib"

5.In your pch.h file add the following line #include "gmock.h".

You should now be able to build all projects and run tests with mocks!
I hope this helped allthough is a little bit long I think it could be automated.